# How many Scalers can be built using three different unit vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products, products

I have three unit vectors in a problem:

$\hat{t}= (\cos(t),0,\sin(t)),$

$ \hat{m}= (0,0,1),$

$\hat{n}= (\sin(th),0,-\cos(th)).$

I know the solution for the problem is:

$(-\sin(2t)+ 5 \sin(2t-4th)+2 \sin(2 th))$

I want to write the answer in a form in which only used variables are unit vectors instead of anges. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited my question to make it more clear. Is it ok now? @mr_e_man

Comment: The middle dimension is never used; all three vectors are in a plane. And you still haven't really given a problem to solve.

Comment: I tried to make the question more clear again. @mr_e_man

Comment: Is it oke now? @mr_e_man

Comment: I guess it makes sense now. Are you sure all the vectors have $y=0$?

Comment: Yes I am sure. @mr_e_man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution can be expanded with the trig identities

$$\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$
$$\cos(2\theta) = \cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)$$
$$\sin(\theta+\phi) = \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)+\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)$$
$$\cos(\theta+\phi) = \cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)-\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$$

to be expressed in terms of $\sin(t)$, $\cos(t)$, $\sin(th)$, and $\cos(th)$.

We also have

$$\hat t\cdot\hat m = \sin(t)$$
$$\hat n\cdot\hat m = -\cos(th)$$
$$\hat t\cdot\hat n = \sin(th-t)$$

but this doesn't give us a way to express $\cos(t)$ or $\sin(th)$ with dot products. (We know that $\cos(t) = \pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2(t)}$ $= \pm\sqrt{1-(\hat t\cdot\hat m)^2}$, but cosine's sign is not determined by the sine.) So I think you must use the components

$$t_x = \hat t\cdot(1,0,0) = \cos(t)$$
$$n_x = \hat n\cdot(1,0,0) = \sin(th)$$